ClickableText composables as a list's elements and use them in lazy column, to list all customers, and when clicked, navigate to other screen
I want to show the list of customer's names in lazy column, so i created a list variable and used clicableText composables inside it, so that each item can be clicked, then i want to use it inside a lazy column to display and can be scrolled vertically, but i logic is not good here, below is my code, i just commented my practice
@Composable
fun allCustomers(navController: NavController) {
    val customerLists = listOf(
        ClickableText(text = AnnotatedString("Customer1"),
            onClick = {}),
        ClickableText(text = AnnotatedString("Customer2"),
            onClick = {}),
        ClickableText(text = AnnotatedString("Customer3"),
            onClick = {}),
        ClickableText(text = AnnotatedString("Customer4"),
            onClick = {}),
        ClickableText(text = AnnotatedString("Customer5"),
            onClick = {}),
        ClickableText(text = AnnotatedString("Customer6"),
            onClick = {}),
        ClickableText(text = AnnotatedString("Customer7"),
            onClick = {}),
        ClickableText(text = AnnotatedString("Customer8"),
            onClick = {}),
        ClickableText(text = AnnotatedString("Customer9"),
            onClick = {}),
        ClickableText(text = AnnotatedString("Customer10"),
            onClick = {}),
    )
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(5.dp),
    ) {
//                           items(1){cus->
//                               customerLists
//                           }
        items(1, itemContent = {
            customerLists.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                customerLists
//                                 Text(text = item,
//                                     color = Color(0xFFFCA4FF),
//                                     fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
//                                     fontSize = 24.sp,
//                                     lineHeight = 120.sp)
            }
        })
    }
}

I tried to show a list of customers, but
Text(
    text = item,
    color = Color(0xFFFCA4FF),
    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
    fontSize = 24.sp,
    lineHeight = 120.sp,
)

above code is not accepted inside lazy column

Composables must be constructed where they are used. Your list should only contain the basic data needed to construct the composable which is then done in your LazyColumn:
@Composable
fun allCustomers(navController: NavController) {
    val customerLists = listOf(
        AnnotatedString("Customer1"),
        AnnotatedString("Customer2"),
        AnnotatedString("Customer3"),
        AnnotatedString("Customer4"),
        AnnotatedString("Customer5"),
        AnnotatedString("Customer6"),
        AnnotatedString("Customer7"),
        AnnotatedString("Customer8"),
        AnnotatedString("Customer9"),
        AnnotatedString("Customer10"),
    )

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(5.dp),
    ) {
        items(customerLists) { customer ->
            ClickableText(text = customer) {
                println("$customer, character clicked: $it")
                navController.navigate(...)
            }
        }
    }
}

